# United Nations people and national interests

Tags: united-nations

The United Nations is allegedly a space to balance national interests.  However, the United Nations is staffed by individuals. The individual representative's interests could be different from their nation's. How is this conflict of interest managed?

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE @lupetto your question is unclear and without any explanation of what are you expecting to answer. I recommend you first take the [Politics.SE Tour](http://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) and then, rewrite your answer.

Comment: I edited to try to bring more clarity. Feel free to roll back if this isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

The first line in the [United Nations webpage on delegates](http://www.un.org/en/sections/resources/delegates/) answers this succinctly

> Delegates represent their countries at UN meetings

Or to put it another way, the delegates do **not** represent themselves. If they were to vote etc contrary to their nation's position they would be recalled.

Comment: You should clarify that you're describing the ideal situation, not necessarily  the corrupt reality